# Linux Mint 19 - mirror iPhone

Tags: iphone, linux, mirror, linux-mint, mirroring

I have been doing some googling to figure out a way to ***mirror my iPhone in Linux Mint 19***, using either USB or WiFi-direct (AirServer-ish).

I've been trying several work-arounds, e.g. Linux' Totem (Video player), using Wine to install **QuickTime Player** (and other mirror-apps for Windows).

I've also tried using **Darling** (a solution for installing Mac OS apps on Linux), but it seems like Darling doesn't work with Linux Mint 19.

I was wondering if anyone could give a, more or less, detailed tutorial on making it possible to mirror iPhone on Linux (Mint 19, that is). I have no trouble using a commercial solution (licensed mirroring apps).

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: ok, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution - using Google Chrome. It costs 4.99$ though.

Follow this link for a detailed description on installing, and using "Mirror to Windows PC":

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mirror-to-windows-pc/id1350663974?mt=8